# Turn a long string with numbers to array

Tags: php, arrays, regex, explode, preg-split

I'm looking for a way to turn a string like `1 hello there 6 foo 37 bar` to an array like:

```
Array ( [1] => "hello there",
        [6] => "foo",
        [37] => "bar" )
```

Each number will be the index of a string that comes after it. I would like to get so help with it. Thanks! :)

Comment: First, SO would like to see your approach first, together with a specific question regarding a specific problem you ran into. Second, [split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the whole thing on spaces, then loop over it using [is_numeric()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) - just one of many ways.

Comment: are numbers unique, or do you have repeats?

Comment: @n3wb numbers are unique. domdom, I was thinking of something with preg_split() but I couldn't make it work so I didn't post it here.

Comment: Check [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) instead.

Comment: However, you need to be careful: what if one of your strings actually contains a number? I would like to know how the input string came about in the first place.

Comment: @domdom they won't. that's for sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution using `preg_match_all` and `array_combine` functions:

```
$str = '1 hello there 6 foo 37 bar';
preg_match_all('/(\d+) +(\D*[^\s\d])/', $str, $m);
$result = array_combine($m[1], $m[2]);

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => hello there 
    [6] => foo 
    [37] => bar
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, you will have the array on $out. Maybe you should consider using regular expressions.

```
$str = '1 hello there 6 foo 37 bar';
$temp = explode(' ', $str);
$out = [];
$key = -1;

foreach ($temp as $word) {
    if (is_numeric($word)) {
        $key = $word;
        $out[$key] = '';
    } else if ($key != -1) {
        $out[$key] .= $word . ' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: Is importance to notice that the usage of regular expressions tend to be slower, although you have less code but lower performance. In this type of cases I intend to use manual manipulation of the string, I use regular expressions for more complex situations.

Comment: The previous solution (by @RomanPerekhrest) executes on 0.016 sec. My solution took 0.012 sec.

Comment: And it can become worse with larger strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex, [live demo](https://eval.in/815853).

```
<?php

$string = '1 hello there 6 foo 37 bar';
preg_match_all('/([\d]+)[\s]+([\D]+)/', $string, $matches);
print_r(array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]));
```

Comment: There is already [a very similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44502775/3316645), maybe you want to point out how yours (the regex, that is) is different (better?)

Comment: and how does your answer principally differs from mine? plagiarism?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest here I don't to argue with you. I swear I haven't seen your code before I paste my code. There is only preg_match_all() to do the regex. How do you say the plagiarism?

Comment: @KrisRoofe, even if it's not plagiarism - you were late posting conceptually the same approach

Comment: Not only was the answer late, it doesn't handle spaces as well as Roman's pattern.  Do a var_export() on the result and see that two elements have a trailing space.